# Sorting strings in Japanese

Tags: java, android, sorting, localization

I am in the process of localizing my android application to Japanese.
I have the localized strings. But for example, when displaying a list, I need the strings to be displayed in an alphabetical order.

Is there a way I can sort Japanese strings alphabetically (because all I see is symbols :P).

Comment: Sorting kanji alphabetically is kind of an oxymoron. What sort do you actually want?

Comment: If you want to sort on hiragana, just find all code points for each letter. Then sorting should be a piece of cake. They may look like symbols to you, but they're just unicode or utf-8 code points to the machine. Then you just need to figure out how you want to treat katakana.

Comment: Sorting japanese is very difficult, see some detailed reasoning: http://www.localizingjapan.com/blog/2011/02/13/sorting-in-japanese-%E2%80%94-an-unsolved-problem/ If you don't have any explicit hard requirements, I would use simply the default collator for the language and accept whatever it gives me.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried using collator:

```
Collator collator = Collator.getInstance(Locale.JAPANESE);
Collections.sort(list, collator);
```

?

Comment: This worked for a list of words in Katakana. Kanji cannot be sorted.

Answer (score 0):

- Use an own `Comparator` examining code points for hiragana and katakana (and romanji), and pass it as an argument of your `sort` invocation.
- For kanji, you're basically on your own, as code points are meaningless for sort operations. It seems like a common issue, if that's any consolation.